# scraping web vba tags nested

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, nested, screen-scraping

I always have problems when I do web scraping with vba if I find tags nested like this in the link

http://forebet.com

scrape the link data from the menu on the left, but  I'm wrong when I get to the championships nested as England, Spain

```
Sub championshipforebet()
Dim objIE As Object
Dim itemEle As Object
Dim itemEle1 As Object
Dim away As Object
Dim desc As String, pt1 As String, pt2 As String, price As String
Dim i As Integer
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://www.forebet.com/it/"
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Set itemEle = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("moduletable_foremenu")(1)
Set itemEle1 = itemEle.getElementsByClassName("tree_foremenu")
i = 1
For Each ele1 In itemEle1(0).getElementsByTagName("li")
    i = i + 1
    Cells(i, 1) = ele1(0).getElementsByClassName("mainlevel_foremenu").href
Next ele1


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no remarkable difference between the two answers, I decided to post mine as I've already created one. The `for loop` part and the `split` function might be helpful for future readers. As QHarr has already described about `.querySelector()` I didn't repeat the same.

This is the code you can try as well:

```
Sub GrabLinks()
    Const Baseurl$ = "https://www.forebet.com"
    Dim S$, I&

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", Baseurl & "/", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        With .querySelectorAll(".mainlevel_foremenu,.sublevel_foremenu")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                Cells(I + 1, 1) = Baseurl & Split(.Item(I).getAttribute("href"), "about:")(1)
            Next I
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: thanks so much to both, but I did not want someone to do it for me but that he told me where I'm wrong without too much change my script, because I do not need a script that works, but I understand, because I like and I'm learning data scraping with vba

Comment: If you are here to learn things anew then you found the wrong site. If you have a minimum knowledge on it then the way `QHarr` has described in his post suffices. However, you can [check out this link to a video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dShR33CdlY8&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=52) to learn things the way you expected.

Comment: If you are just learning this for fun, consider using Python and R to scrape sites.  I think both technologies are far superior for these kinds of things.  http://srome.github.io/Parsing-HTML-Tables-in-Python-with-BeautifulSoup-and-pandas/   http://bradleyboehmke.github.io/2015/12/scraping-html-tables.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selectors including the OR operator `","`. Also, use [XMLHTTPRequest (XHR)](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) to retrieve the data far more quickly than by opening IE.

---

The links are in one of two classes:

The top level have class:

```
mainlevel_foremenu
```

[image: img 1]

The nested have class:

```
sublevel_foremenu
```

[image: img2]

---

You can use a CSS selector combination to get all elements with either of these two classes, combining them with the OR operator.

```
a.mainlevel_foremenu,a.sublevel_foremenu
```

The `a` means `a` tag ([element selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element.asp))  and the `.` is a [class selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp). So elements with an `a` tag that have class name `mainlevel_foremenu`, or (`","`) `sublevel_foremenu`. The `a` is not actually required in this instance so you could shorten to `.mainlevel_foremenu, .sublevel_foremenu`.

The CSS selector returns more than one item so `.querySelectorAll` method of `document` is used to return a `nodeList`. The length of the `nodeList` is then iterated to access individual links by index.

The links are relative so `Replace` function is used to remove the `"about:"` and the base path is prefixed to the link address.

---

If we look at the first switch on the page:

[image: img]

The combined CSS selector results show we are also getting the nested level (note I have cut out some of the intermediary results).

[image: img]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Application.Screenupdating = False
    Dim sResponse As String, i As Long, html As New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.forebet.com/", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    Dim links As Object
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set links = .querySelectorAll("a.mainlevel_foremenu,a.sublevel_foremenu")
    End With
    For i = 0 To links.Length - 1
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = "https://www.forebet.com" & Replace$(links(i).href, "about:", vbNullString)
    Next i
    Application.Screenupdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Sample results:**

[image: sample]

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: @ryguy72 That is a kind thing to say. Thank you.

Comment: @plinius - there should be enough info in my answer above for you to work out where your script needs to be amended. I have highlighted what you need to target. I may use a different access method but the rest is exactly the same. There are two different classes to handle and you are only looking at one would pretty much be the simple answer. My solution is to use an OR operator to handle the two cases of interest.